# Converting unicode symbols to their code

Tags: java, unicode

I have the following XML file which contains emojis symbols: http://pastebin.com/8f0GeE96

Now, what I want is to convert each unicode character to it's code (as a string). I've wrote the following code for this cause. The problem is that I get many dup's (i.e. `d83d`) and it make me think something is wrong with my parsing. What's  the explanation for that?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        File file = new File("c:\\EmojisList.plist.txt");

        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                       new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF8"));

            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) { 
                if(str.trim().startsWith("<string>"))
                {
                    int emoji_pos = str.indexOf('>') + 1;
                    char emoji_char = str.charAt(emoji_pos);
                    String emoji_code_str = Integer.toHexString(emoji_char);

                    System.out.println(emoji_code_str);
                }

            }

            in.close();


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unicode standard started out with a range of characters for which 16 bits (two bytes) was sufficient.

However, more and more scripts and symbols were added to it, and nowadays, you can't express all the characters with 16 bits. The legal range of code points is from U+0 through U+10FFFF.

Unfortunately, that does not fit inside a Java `char`, which only has 16 bits and is capable of representing values 0 through FFFF.

Most common western languages don't have a problem with this - the range for Latin including accents, Russian, Arabic, Hebrew, etc. is well within the 16 bit range. Even the common Chinese and Japanese characters are within that range.

But most emojis are actually in the "extended" range, in the unicode "Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs" and "Emoticon" blocks, which range from U+1F300 through U+1F5FF and from U+1F600 through U+1F67F respectively.

Characters in this range are represented in strings using the UTF-16 encoding, which basically uses two `char` values for each such character. So if a character's *code point* (its official unicode value) is in the range U+10000 through U+10FFFF, two `char` values, one from the range U+D800 through U+DB7F ("high surrogates"), and one from the range U+DC00 through U+DFFF ("low surrogates"), are used to represent it.

So when you read the value of `charAt(emoji_pos)` in your program, you are actually reading only the first half of the actual character. Indeed, all the emojis in the "Emoticon" range have a high surrogate character of U+D83D.

So, to get the actual Unicode code point of the emoji, you need to translate the UTF-16 representation to an actual `int` value. A `char` will not suffice. And you do this by using methods available to you in the `String` and `Character` classes.

Instead of using `charAt`, in this case you can simply use the [`codePointAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt%28int%29) method.

So, instead of

```
char emoji_char = str.charAt(emoji_pos);
```

Use:

```
int emojiCodePoint = str.codePoint(emojiPos);
```

For further information, read the [UTF FAQ](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) at the Unicode Consortium's web site.

---

Note: the Java coding conventions are that variable, field an method names should be in lower camel case: the first word starts with a lowercase letter, the other words start with upper case, and *no underscores*. So variable names should be `emojiCodePoint`, not `emoji_code_point`. Underscores are only acceptable in constant names, which are all-uppercase (e.g. `CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`).

Comment: Thank you so much  for this detailed answer!

Comment: Quite Unfortunately even the codePointAt method returns a surrogate value rather than an actual codepoint. Really weird, while charAt gives '\uDE00' 56832, codePointAt gives 56832. And this is the concerned emoji 